# Laravel File Downloaded from storage folder gets corrupted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to download jpg/png image from storage folder its gets corrupted after downloaded.
This is my controller

```
public function download($filename) {

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: image/png',
    );
    return response()->download(storage_path() . '/'.$filename, 'final.png', $headers);

}
```

after open it look like this
[image]

Even i used core php script to download still iam facing same problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe that the Laravel framework might be introducing whitespace which might be ruining the header() function.

Use ob_end_clean() before your first header() call to remove any extra whitespace.

Comment: What? Seems very random to me. Do I just have to add this function in every endpoint? Is there any way to do this central in Laravel 8?

Comment: 4h wasted on this. Thanks man!

Answer (score 13):

add this method before like this

```
ob_end_clean();
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: image/png',
);
return response()->download(storage_path() . '/'.$filename, 'final.png', $headers);
```

!enjoy

Answer (score 0):

[After Download .jpg,png,gif and .xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAuuX.jpg)
Yes ! Its working;
I was reading this problem for 15 days and finally got the solution

- Larabel 5.8 & PHP 7.3

```html
public function download_user_photo($id) {
    ob_end_clean();
    $photo = UserGallery::find($id);
    $path = 'storage/users/'.$photo->image_url;
    enter code here
        if (\File::exists($path)) {
            return response()->download($path);
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->with('danger', 'Image does not exist.');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem as well

```
ob_end_clean();
        $headers = [
            'Content-type' => 'application/zip',
            'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename='$name.zip'",
            'Cache-Control'=>'private'
        ];
```

By adding `ob_end_clean();` before the headers array I was able to get my zip file downloaded without any corruptions!